# Proper way to destroy a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I've looked at similar question to no avail. I have a fragment that hosts a ViewPager (it is a report wizard). When the users completes the wizard, it redirects them to a new Fragment that confirms the report is complete. I want to destroy the ViewPager fragment entirely so that my users may start fresh if they attempt to do another. I tried popping the back stack after moving out of the ViewPager fragment and into the completed fragment, but I get recursive errors. Is there a proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just don't do anything, not even adding it to the back stack. The old `Fragment` will be garbage collected once no references exist anymore and it doesn't sound like you really need this `Fragment` to be in the back stack anyway.

Comment: The problem with that though is that if a user starts to fill out a report, goes to a different part of my app, and then comes back to it, I don't want to lose that.

Comment: But adding the `Fragment` to the back stack is the wrong way to achieve this. The back stack is used to build a navigation hierarchy with `Fragments` and not to save the instance state of a `Fragment`. If you want to permanently persist the data then save it in the `SharedPreferences`. If you don't need it persisted permanently I would just save everything in the outBundle in `onSaveInstanceState()`. Doing it this way is no guarantee that the data will be around for long, but it should work if the user returns to the `Fragment` fast enough.